# Cambiar imagen con mouseover

Tags: javascript

Teniendo un evento `mouseover`, quisiera que al pasar el mouse por encima de la imagen, la imagen cambie dependiendo de cual sea la imagen actual, sino, no se cambia.

## HTML

```
<body>
 <img src="ikefeliz_2.png" id="imagen">
</body>
```

### JS

```
var ikefeliz="ikefeliz_2.png";
var marthfeliz="marthfeliz_2.png";
var ikepeligro="ikepeligro_2.png";
var marthpeligro="marthpeligro_2.png";

window.addEventListener('load', iniciar, false);

function iniciar(){
  var imagen=document.getElementById('imagen');
  imagen.addEventListener('mouseover', peligro, false);
 }

function peligro(){
  var imagen=document.getElementById('imagen');
  switch (imagen.src) {
    case ikefeliz:
     document.getElementById('imagen').src=ikepeligro;
     break;

    case marthfeliz:
     document.getElementById('imagen').src=marthpeligro;
     break;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Codigo

```js
var imagenNormal = "http://requirementsinc.com/img/icon/PNG/danger.png";

var imagenPeligro = "https://img.utdstc.com/icons/256/app-danger-check-android.png";

var imagenExtra = "https://www.technodyan.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/LinuxAndroid.png";

window.addEventListener('load', iniciar, false);

function iniciar() {

  var imagen = document.getElementById('imagen');
  
  imagen.addEventListener('mouseover', peligro, false);
}

function peligro() {

  var imagen = document.getElementById('imagen');

  switch(imagen.src){
  
    case imagenNormal:
      document.getElementById('imagen').src = imagenPeligro;
      break;
      
    case imagenPeligro:
      document.getElementById('imagen').src = imagenExtra;
      break;
  
    case imagenExtra:
      alert("No debo cambiar la imagen");
      break;
  
  }

}
```

```html
<body>
  <img src="http://requirementsinc.com/img/icon/PNG/danger.png" id="imagen">
</body>
```

---

### Explicacion

No es necesario que hagas esto:

```
var imagen=document.getElementById('imagen').src="ikepeligro_2.png";
```

Ya que `imagen` fue declarada previamente y **cualquier cambio que realices en el objeto, siempre lo mantendrá actualizado**.

Lo que he hecho es simplificar un poco el código, **usando** la sentencia `switch` y dejando los nombres de las imágenes en variables, así puedes hacer uso de una comparación y en caso que sea una u otra imagen puedes hacer el cambio.

Comment: He usado hace tiempo el switch en c++ y entiendo como funciona. Veo claro tu código y he intentado copiarlo pero no obstante no consigo que me funcione. Voy a despejarme un poco y en un tiempo lo vuelvo a intentar. Muchísimas gracias de nuevo.

Comment: @Vendetta Dale, despejate un poco y si no entiendes algo aca estoy presto a ayudarte :)

Comment: La edite siguiendo sus pasos. Igual algo fallo, no se que puede ser

Comment: @Vendetta Podrias agregar una edicion y mostrarnos lo que has intentado de mas? Por favor para mirar que error puedes tener

Comment: Acabo de editar el código, si es a eso a lo que te refieres. Puedo subirlo a la web por si quieres ojearlo mejor.

Comment: @Vendetta Si, si lo puedes subir en la web o mostrar un ejemplo del sitio podria hechar un ojo al js

Comment: Aquí puedes verlo:" equipostaff.hol.es "   Seguramente mi código sea muy desordenada y poco práctico y tampoco te pido que gastes mas tiempo del necesario. Muchas gracias

Comment: @Vendetta Has probado quitando el diseño del cursor?